# Solaris: How to de-register/de-list a package installed with pkgadd

Tags: package, solaris

We have uninstalled an application on several Solaris servers manually by deleting folders and files only to realize afterwards that it had been installed with a package through pkgadd.

The command pkginfo -l, still shows the package even though its files are gone. Is there a way to simply "de-register" the package so it doesn't show up anymore with pkginfo?

Comment: Note sure if it's the good way to do it, but I have deleted the package folder in /var/sadm/pkg and it worked. Would this be ok?

Comment: Have you tried just running `pkgrm` for the package?

Comment: That's not an option, and yes, but it doesn't work since some of the required files are missing, it fails. The problem is the start/stop script of service the package will stop during its uninstall has a bug, and it could affect local zones. The only way to avoid this, is to stop the service manually only for the global zone and then delete the package. It's a long story and it's complicated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as `/var/sadm/pkg` you should also check `/var/sadm/install/contents`, and the man page `contents(4)` for the same (`man -s4 contents`).